# What javascript event is triggered if ios low power mode is turned on in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, video, safari

I have a webpage that use html video and javascript to access the camera and allow the user to capture a frame.

```
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline></video>
```

This works fine on iphones until the "low power mode" is turned on. When the low power mode is turned on, safari overrides my styles and adds a play button on the screen. I want to be able to detect using javascript when low power mode is turned on so that I can add my own custom styles.

Is there a way I can achieve this? I found answers asking to use the "suspend" event handler. However, I found that safari emits this even with low power mode turned off and as a result I cannot rely on it.

Thanks.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Unfortunately. It doesnt. The accepted answer is to use the suspend event. I tried using it. It is emitted even without low power mode turned on.

Comment: It is not the answer with the most votes ( rather than "accepted" ) that is relevant - the answer by @TamásSengel that seems most appropriate - namely `"Safari on iOS does not support accessing the status of the low power mode setting (it does not even support accessing the battery level)."`